# use tornado.httpclient to access twitter

Tags: python, tornado

I'm reading the book Introduction to Tornado. I'm trying to use tornado.httpclient to access twitter api. In their example they use old v1 search api which is not supported. The one supported of v1.1 require oauth authentication.

In my case, I have all the oauth info available (e.g. token and secret for app and for the user). However, I cannot figure out how to combine them with the current fetch call:

```
response = client.fetch("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=football&result_type=recent&rpp=100")
```

The question is how to change this call to add to it the oauth support. I did similar thing with the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), where I just had to add OAuth1 object to the call.

```
ua = OAuth1(client_key=TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
            client_secret=TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, 
            resource_owner_key=token,
            reource_owner_secret=secret,signature_type='auth_header')


requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json",
              auth=ua,
              params=dict(q="football",result_type="recent",rpp=100))
```

Can I do something similar to the requests library in the tornado.httpclient ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `tornado.httpclient` module doesn't have any support for OAuth, but the `tornado.auth` module does.  Subclass `tornado.auth.TwitterMixin` and use its `twitter_request` method.

Comment: thanks. I saw this twitter_request, but this supports the full cycle including making a call to the twitter server for getting the keys and store them in cookie. I was looking for something much simpler.